# how to get data in the variable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Tags: c++, curl

how to get data in the variable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION?

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);

Comment: Why does it matter? Just set the option to what you want.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to do or what the problem is. Doesn't that `curl_easy_setopt` line do what you want?

Comment: The question doesn't parse. You just don't get data in that "variable".

Answer (score 0):

I see you have posted a number of similar questions about `libcurl` here. Please find a reference for `libcurl` and read it. Here is one:

http://tuvix.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/libcurl-easy.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/libcurl-easy

> When all is setup, you tell libcurl to perform the transfer using curl_easy_perform(3).  It will then
>   do the entire operation and won't return until it is done (successfully or not).

So, you get information from `curl_easy_perform`. There is no data to get from `curl_easy_setopt` because its purpose is to accept information from you.

Or, you might be looking for the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` argument to `curl_easy_setopt` which tells `libcurl` to print debugging information. It is impossible to tell from the question.